# dataframe condition on multiple columns in python

Tags: pandas, list, dataframe, python-3.6

dataframe:

```
i_id    sg_yes_or_no
i-123   yes
i-123   yes
i-456   no
i-678   yes
i-1y6   yes
i-1y6   yes
```

Expected output should be:

```
i_id    sg_yes_or_no    sg_only_one sg_morethan_one
i-123   yes                         yes
i-123   yes                         yes
i-456   no      
i-678   yes             yes 
i-1y6   yes                         yes
i-1y6   yes                         yes
```

or

```
i_id    sg_yes_or_no    
i-123   more_sg         
i-123   more_sg           
i-456   no      
i-678   one_sg             
i-1y6   more_sg             
i-1y6   more_sg
```

Tried to use the below syntax but its not working:

```
for df['sg_yes_or_no'] in 'yes':
    if df['i_id'].nunique() == 1:
        df['sg_only_one'] = 'yes'
    elif df['i_id'].nunique() >= 1:
        df['sg_morethan_one'] = 'yes'
```

If the 2nd column is "yes" take the new_dataframe in to consideration and check (count) the 1st column value in the new_dataframe. if the count is 1 then write yes in 3rd column (or update the 2nd column with "one_sg"), if the count is more than 1 then write yes in 4th column (or update the 2nd column with "more_sg").

please assist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

an elegant solution with [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html#pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table):

```
new_df = df.join(df.pivot_table(columns = (df.groupby('i_id')['i_id']
                   .transform('size')
                   .gt(1)), 
                                values='sg_yes_or_no', 
                                index=df.index, 
                                aggfunc='first')
                  .rename(columns={False : 'sg_only_one',
                                   True : 'sg_morethan_one'})
                  .mask(lambda x: x.eq('no'))
                  .sort_index(axis=1, ascending=False))
```

---

```
print(new_df)
    i_id sg_yes_or_no sg_only_one sg_morethan_one
0  i-123          yes         NaN             yes
1  i-123          yes         NaN             yes
2  i-456           no         NaN             NaN
3  i-678          yes         yes             NaN
4  i-1y6          yes         NaN             yes
5  i-1y6          yes         NaN             yes
```

We can also use:

```
m1 = df.groupby('i_id')['i_id'].transform('size').gt(1)
m2 = df['sg_yes_or_no'].ne('no')
df['sg_morethan_one'] = df['sg_yes_or_no'].where(m & m2)
df['sg_only_one'] = df['sg_yes_or_no'].where(~m & m2)
```

This is possibly much more efficient when there are only two categories, but for n categories the `pivot_table` option is better, in addition `pivot_table` avoids applying n times `Series.where`

**EDIT**

```
new_df = df.join(df.pivot_table(columns = (df.groupby('i_id')['i_id']
                                             .transform('size')
                                             .gt(1)
                                             .astype(int)
                                             .mask(df['sg_yes_or_no'].eq('no'), 2)), 
                                values='sg_yes_or_no', 
                                index=df.index, 
                                aggfunc='first')
                  .rename(columns={0 : "one_sg",
                                   1 : "more_sg",
                                   2 : "no_sg"})
                  .sort_index(axis=1, ascending=False))
print(new_df)
    i_id sg_yes_or_no one_sg no_sg more_sg
0  i-123          yes    NaN   NaN     yes
1  i-123          yes    NaN   NaN     yes
2  i-456           no    NaN    no     NaN
3  i-678          yes    yes   NaN     NaN
4  i-1y6          yes    NaN   NaN     yes
5  i-1y6          yes    NaN   NaN     yes
```

Comment: Its not working @ansev.
Can i update the sg_yes_or_no with the "no_sg", "one_sg" and "more_sg" ? 
If i use this code, i am getting empty 3rd and 4th column, nothing in it.

Comment: This code works for sample dataframe( TWO Categories), I Have updated the code for  "no_sg", "one_sg" and "more_sg", please check section EDIT. 
Consider accepting or voting the answer to value the work

Comment: Hi, Its working, but can we update the 2nd column ?
Instead of adding three additional columns ?
I edited my question, please see second expected answer.

Comment: `df['sg_yes_or_no'] = (df.groupby('i_id')['i_id']
                                             .transform('size')
                                             .gt(1)
                                             .astype(int)
                                             .mask(df['sg_yes_or_no'].eq('no'), 2)).map({0 : "one_sg",
                                   1 : "more_sg",
                                   2 : "no_sg"})`